# Script counting unchecked form elements

Tags: javascript

In my script, a few things are happening and I'm not sure why:

- If someone skips Q2, I get a console error.
- If someone answers only Q2 (skips Q1 and/or Q3), it counts the value of Q2 twice.

Is there something I should have in here that indicates to skip things if they aren't checked? I thought that's in there with the first if statement? (i.e., form.q2[i].checked)

```
function process() {
  var okay = 0;
  var bad = 0;

  var form = document.myForm;
  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < form.q2.length; i++)
    if (form.q2[i].checked) value = form.q2[i].value;
  if (value == "1") {
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "2") {
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "3") {
    okay++;
  }


  for (i = 0; i < form.q3.length; i++)
    if (form.q3[i].checked) value = form.q3[i].value;
  if (value == "1") {
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "2") {
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "3") {
    okay++;
  }


  var out = "bad";
  i = bad;

       if (okay > i && document.getElementById('q1').value=="0") {out = "bad"; i=bad;}
          
      if (okay > i && document.getElementById('q1').value=="1") {out = "okay"; i=okay;}
           
      if (bad >= i && document.getElementById('q1').value=="0") {out = "bad"; i=bad;}
           
      if (bad >= i && document.getElementById('q1').value=="1") {out = "okay"; i=okay;}  
    
           console.log(bad);
           console.log(okay);
           
//  location.href = out;
}

function err(msg, url, line) {
  location.href = "error.html";
}
```

```
    <form name="myForm">

        <b>How are you feeling?</b><br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="0">Bad<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="1">Good<br><br>

        <b>Question 1</b><br>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">Answer 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2">Answer 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3">Answer 3<br><br>

        <b>Question 2</b><br>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">Answer 1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="2">Answer 2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="q3" value="3">Answer 3<br><br>

        <input type="button" value="Show Results" onclick="process();">
        <br>
        <br>
    </form>
```

Comment: Important to note that you can't repeat element ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. Think of them like an address then send mail to someone who's address is duplicated 20 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never declare the `value` variable. The only time it is assigned a value is inside of this for loop when you are checking question 2:

```js
for (i = 0; i < form.q2.length; i++)
    if (form.q2[i].checked) value = form.q2[i].value;
```

When you check `value` on the next line, it will only have a value if question 2 was answered. Otherwise it will be `undefined`

Declare the variable above with your others and give it an initial value:

```js
var okay = 0;
var bad = 0;

var form = document.myForm;
var i = 0;

var value = 0;
```

The reason question 2 is counted twice is because you assign a value to `value` if question 2 is answered. Even though the `for` loop for question 3 never runs, the variable `value` still has the value it had from question number 2. So, the counter will be incremented again unless you reset the value of `value` to 0 or use a different variable to track the value for each question

```js
function process() {
  var okay = 0;
  var bad = 0;

  var form = document.myForm;
  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < form.q2.length; i++)
    if (form.q2[i].checked) value = form.q2[i].value; // value gets set here if question 2 is answered
  if (value == "1") {
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "2") {
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "3") {
    okay++;
  }


  for (i = 0; i < form.q3.length; i++)
    if (form.q3[i].checked) value = form.q3[i].value;
  if (value == "1") { // value here still has value from question 2 if for loop above is skipped
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "2") {
    bad++;
  }
  if (value == "3") {
    okay++;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. That solves the "value" undefined error, but I'm still having an issue where if someone only answers Q2 (and skips the other two), it counts the value of that twice.

Comment: The reason that is happening is because you assign a value to `value` if question 2 is answered. Even thought the `for` loop for question 3 never runs, the variable `value` still has the value it had from question number 2. So, the counter will be incremented again unless you reset the value of `value` to `0` or use a different variable to track the value for each question.